# Japanese 使役｛しえき} and 使役{しえき}受身{うけみ} grammar

Tags: grammar, translation, causation, giving-and-receiving

> その映画から、事故で子供を死なせてしまった母親の悲しさが伝わってきた。

from this sentence,

> Translation: conveyed the sadness of the mothers of the children who killed in accident

or

> conveyed the sadness of the children whom mother was killed in accident

and also I don't understand why they used shieki and not shieki ukemi.

Besides that also the particle を is really confusing, who is the subject and also the object in this sentence 「じこでこどもをしなせてしまった」 ?

Could you explain to me?

Comment: This is very confusing to read.  I suggest editing it to use proper grammar (as best as you can if English is not your first language)  and punctuation.  Also, your statement `the particle を is really confusing` is ambiguous because there are two を's in the sentence.

Comment: Im sorry i tried my best

Comment: Can you give a little more context from before this sentence?

Comment: Also, are you only asking about the 「事故で子供を死なせてしまった母親」part, or do you also what to know about 「悲しさを伝わってきた」?

Comment: I don't want to nitpick but is there a reason that you have used "sieki" in the title and "shieki" within the question?

Comment: Are you sure it's 悲しさ**を**伝わってきた, not 悲しさ**が**伝わってきた?

Comment: ＠chocolate thanks for correcting me! the correct one is 悲しさが伝わってきた

Answer (score 2):

“その映画から、事故で子供を死なせてしまった母親の悲しさが伝わってきた” can be translated as;

The movie conveyed heartrending sorrow of the mother who lost her child by an (a traffic) accident.
The sadness (sorrow) is clearly that of mother, not the child.

The verbatim translation of “事故で子供を死なせてしまった母親” is “the mother who made her child die / killed,” but it doesn’t mean the mother killed the child, and no mother under the sun "allows" and "permits" somebody to kill her child. The accident killed the child.

It’s better to interpret ”子供を死なせてしまった母親” as “the mother who lost her child” than “the mother who made her child be killed.”

The subject in the sentence is “母親の悲しみ - the sorrow of mother,” which is followed by the verb, “伝わってきた – was conveyed.”

Answer (score 1):

「子供を死なせる」 means to "allow", or "cause" the death of this child.

So 「事故で**子供を死なせてしまった**母親」 would mean something like:

> the mother who **caused** (her) child's death in an accident

The mother is the subject. The child is the object. The mother is the one who causes the child's death.

If you put the 使役{しえき} of 「死ぬ」 into 受身｛うけみ｝ it would look like this:

```
死なせる　⇒　死なせられる
```

> 「事故で**子供を死なせられてしまった**母親」

It's kind of hard to imagine what this would mean though. Maybe someone else (not the mother) would have caused the child's death? But that's probably a bit of a stretch.

Comment: i think someone else cause the accident, but there is a kind of feeling that the mother let her child dead(?) although its not her mother fault right?

Comment: In the original example sentence you could understand it either way. させる does not draw a clear distinction between "permitting" something to happen and "causing" something to happen. You have to guess from the context. So maybe it is the mother's fault, but maybe it isn't.